# How can I perform the same traffic shaping on all transmit queues

Tags: linux, networking, linux-kernel, tc

I'm trying to use the `mq` qdisc for performance but I need to add other qdiscs below it to shape traffic.  It seems natural to me that one would want the same shaping, regardless of queue and it seems a lot of work to have to add the same tree of qdiscs and classes to each of the `mq` classes under the root.  (To say nothing of the fact that a complex tree eats a lot of major numbers when you have to replicate it for each queue.)

I'm not a kernel expert by any means but I've poked around the source and I see in `sch_mq.c` that the `attach` function (and a couple of others) iterate over the transmit queues.  That mildly suggested to me that if I did:

```
tc qdisc add dev ifc root handle 1: mq
tc qdisc add dev ifc parent 1:1 handle 2: htb
```

That the `htb` behavior might be attached to each 1:1, 1:2, etc. but at least `tc qdisc show` still shows the default qdiscs on 1:2, etc.

Is there a way to get the same shaping on every queue without cloning the qdisc tree and burning major numbers?